# Why the loop can't stop?

Tags: python, loops, break

I have a problem that the loop doesn't want to stop.

```
f = open(the_file[0], "w+b")
recvd = " "
while True:
    data = s.recv(4096)
    if not data: 
        print("Done") 
        break
    recvd += str(data)
f.write(recvd)
f.close()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The other end of the socket isn't closing the connection.

Comment: `s.recv()` (assuming it's a socket) will never exit, unless there's data. There for, there will always be data.

Comment: @Torxed It will also return an empty string when the socket is closed. The loop is intended to stop when that happens.

Comment: So i have to close the connection on the server?

Comment: In case you are using UDP (you did not show the socket initialization) it will never break.

Comment: @KlausD. I understand. Well i try an other method to solve this problem. I already have an idea.